# Best practice for loading non model data in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, viewmodel

Let's assume that I have 2 tables in my database, a user table and a folder table. They are matched by two models (beans) in my backend java code and similarly by to models in my extjs client side. Using viewmodel architecture, I want to create a `form` that shows the `username` and the ***amount*** of folders they have created using ***viewmodel bindings***. Each folder in the database has a `CREATE_USER_ID` field that contains the id of the user that created the folder. How do I go about loading the required data?

Answer (score 0):

Viewmodels are not designed to load data directly (and not designed to load non model data at all). You've got two options:

1. Go model (recommended). Two sub-options:

   - Add `folder_amount` field to your client side user model. On the server side this does not necessarily need to be added as well as you can adjust your API feeding data to client to add that field dynamically.
   - If you want to keep your client models exactly matching their server mates, use viewmodel in conjunction with associations (see example [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.app.ViewModel), scroll down to Associations) to load folders themselves, though in the UI only show the amount of them. Mind that you don't need to load all folder fields but just their IDs.
2. Stick to your own fancy non model approach, but this won't have anything to do with viewmodel bindings. This may be, for example, making an AJAX call to retrieve the number of folders when user data is rendered in the UI.

Comment: Once again my question is not understood. I dont want to load user's folder, I want to load the **amount** of folders the user has created. This has nothing to do with associations. Dont get stuck on the viewmodel binding thing the question is about the loading process. Viewmodels come in after we've loaded the required data and how we will handle it for our view. Do we create a new field for the view model? Maybe a custom temporary model?

Comment: From the point of view of the client/browser side of your app, the *amount* of folders a user has is just another field in the user model. What would be the point in regarding it as separate non-model data as far as client side is concerned? Just keep it simple. If you don't want your server side user model to have the amount of folders cached in a field as well, then just adjust your API feeding user data to the client so that it adds `folder_amount` field dynamically.

Comment: Well the goal is for the client modelsto match the back end models for consistency reasons. I believe it is bad practice to add a new field to a model every time you want to show composite and non referenced information. Isnt this why we have view models? To give the view that pre processed info through bindings?

Comment: Consistency between server and client models should not be a goal on its own (unless it's a religion to you) because they have different purposes. Server models exist for storing data and business logic. Client models are just reflections of their server mates for UI purposes. There may be cases where maintaining the consistency does not add value but wastes effort; this should be looked at case-by-case. In your case, I guess the amount of folders will be merely displayed (vs. edited) on the frontend, therefore you can safely make the frontend think of it as just another field. Answer updated.

Comment: The thing is, adding a field will make it accessible via viewmodel bindings but since my rest api `GET` request won't load the folder amount by itself I am required to make another 'custom' ajax request just to get this particular information. Whether I put it in a model field afterwards or just straight set the value into a `displayfield` ends being more a matter of preference. Is it good practice to dynamically change the model's proxy's rest api to match a new service that will also bring the extra info? Or should I just go with one extra ajax request for the sake of simplicity?

Comment: Nope, dynamically tampering with your client's proxy's ends is bodgy and ugly. As far as the client side of your app is concerned, `folder_amount` should be regarded just as a field of the user model, and therefore the best practice would be to adjust your server side to it: either add the field to your server side user model so that it caches the actual amount of folders and gets updated when the amount changes, OR make your API to inject that field dynamically. Otherwise, the second best practice is using associations and loading folders themselves just to see and display their amount.